# virtualenv/condaenv in Rshiny app using reticulate

Tags: python, anaconda, virtualenv, conda, reticulate

I am working on deploying an app in RShiny that uses the Reticulate package.

When running the app locally I have no issues as a virtual environment is not needed but once I try to create the virtual environment in R, this is my code:

`py_install(envname='py_env_FF', method = 'virtualenv', conda='auto', packages=c('pandas', 'numpy')) Error: Installing Python packages into a virtualenv is not supported on Windows`

I also tried the "auto" method as below but still no luck:
py_install(envname='py_env_FF', method = 'auto', conda='auto', packages=c('pandas', 'numpy','joblib', 'requests', 'geopy', 'sklearn'), pip =TRUE) Sys.setenv('py_env_FF')

Here is the error:

`C:\Users\Analytics\Documents>conda.bat activate py_env_FF
'pip' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
Error: Error 1 occurred installing packages into conda environment py_env_FF
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In normalizePath(path.expand(path), winslash, mustWork) :
path[1]="C:\Users\Analytics\Anaconda3\envs\py_env_2\envs\py_env_FF/python.exe": The system cannot find the file specified
2: In normalizePath(path.expand(path), winslash, mustWork) :
path[1]="C:\Users\Analytics\Anaconda3\envs\py_env_FF/python.exe": The system cannot find the file specified
3: In normalizePath(path.expand(path), winslash, mustWork) :
path[1]="C:\Users\Analytics\Documents\py_env_FF/python.exe": The system cannot find the file specified
4: In normalizePath(path.expand(path), winslash, mustWork) :
path[1]="C:\Users\Analytics\Anaconda3\envs\py_env_2\envs\py_env_FF/python.exe": The system cannot find the file specified
5: In normalizePath(path.expand(path), winslash, mustWork) :
path[1]="C:\Users\Analytics\Anaconda3\envs\py_env_FF/python.exe": The system cannot find the file specified
6: In normalizePath(path.expand(path), winslash, mustWork) :
path[1]="C:\Users\Analytics\Documents\py_env_FF/python.exe": The system cannot find the file specified`

Previously I also tried manually creating a conda virtual environment using command, but apparently conda environments are not compatible with RShiny.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Try it with `method='conda'` and don't use `pip`.

Comment: I have to use pip for sklearn because you cant install sklearn with conda

Comment: If you mean that you need to use `import sklearn`, the package is (very confusingly) different from the module name. The package is `scikit-learn` and that is on Conda. [The only `sklearn` on PyPI](https://pypi.org/project/sklearn/) is a just a stub that reads: "Use `scikit-learn` instead."